# Build docker image jar file : COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have a leshan server jar file (to which I have made some changes) obtained by running the maven clean install. I specify that I work in linux and I put this jar file inside a "leshan_docker" folder contained in the desktop. within the same folder there is also a dockerfile to build the server image, and it is written as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

COPY /Desktop/leshan_docker/leshan-server-demo-*.jar /Desktop/leshan_docker/  

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/leshan-server-demo-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

but when I go to build through this command:

```
sudo docker build -f Dockerfile3 -t leshan-server3 .
```

It reports me the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon     12MB
Step 1/3 : FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
 ---> f7a292bbb70c
Step 2/3 : COPY /Desktop/leshan_docker/leshan-server-demo-*.jar /Desktop/leshan_docker/
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

How can I go about solving the problem? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I doubt that a folder `/Desktop` exists. Did you by any chance mean `/home/<username>/Desktop`?

Comment: There is no `Desktop` directory in the root folder for linux. Specify the absolute path. Same goes for the destination.

Comment: you mean like that: /home/<username>/Desktop/leshan_docker/...? or only "leshan_docker" folder? @RatulSharker

Comment: cd into your `/Desktop/leshan_docker/` then run `pwd` it will show you the absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source path with the `COPY` command should be relative to the build context. Your build context is in the folder you're running `sudo docker build` in since the final argument you gave was `.`. I highly recommend taking a look at [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

The destination path for the `COPY` command should be relative to the path in your container. What may work now is to move your `.jar` to the root directory and run it from there.

So if your jar files are in the same directory you're running the command in, change it to:

```
COPY leshan-server-demo-*.jar /
```

It would be better practice to actually create a new directory in the container to hold your `.jar` file to keep your work more organized.

Comment: Ok perfect it worked, sorry but i am still new to docker, and i had to do this for a university project. Thanks again for your help and thanks for the explanation now I understand what I was wrong! @tentative

Comment: You're welcome! I understand, I'm a uni student too. @GianmarcoPlutino